# Permission denied with mkdir?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory using Codeigniter. But it gives me this error:

```
Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied.
```

Here's the code:

```
        $imageDir   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . 'public' . DS . 'images' . DS . 'products';
        $userDir = $imageDir . DS . $userId;

        if (!is_file($userDir) && !is_dir($userDir)) {
            if (!mkdir($userDir)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I already changed the permissions to 777 but the problem still stands.

Comment: Don't see any code, thus I just guess: You give an invalid path. Try debugging...

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code and even a directory listing (`ls -l`) of where you are trying to create the directory.

Comment: If you echo out `$userDir`, what does it show? Also, a directory listing (`ls -l`) of where you are trying to create the directory would be good too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$imageDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/public/images/products/';
$userDir = $imageDir . $userId;
```

and try to echo $userDir so that you can find the path where it is making the directory.